# Ubuntu 20:04 boot logo image after costumazation

Tags: 20.04, customization, plymouth, customizer, ubuntu-builder

I'm using Cubic to create a new ISO and i have a problem with this ubuntu logo image.

[image]

In Cubic chroot i have already changed the image of the ubuntu logo but this after making the build continues to appear before the installation phase, while after the installation it fades for the "new" image. Could you please help me?

Comment: After changing the image I think you should update your initramfs via : "update-initramfs -u" since plymouth service shows that image even before the actual filesystem gets mounted . So it resides in the initramfs archive.

Comment: I tried but the problem was not solved. I have updated the image that is presented to me and that I want to change. Do you think the problem could be solved by not checking the disk before installation (if possible)? and if yes, how, please

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the cubic itself which might ignore the plymouth theme for the live system and install the default one but the installer actually installs the plymouth theme that you've specified. Who knows.

Comment: Each linux iso file contains an archive called filesystem.squashfs . You can mount the contents of it via [squashfs tools](https://askubuntu.com/questions/437880/extract-a-squashfs-to-an-existing-directory) to a directory and examine it to figure out what the cubic actually have done.

Comment: I have verified that in the usr /share/plymouth folder of the squashfs archive everything is in rules, and indeed it is. So I don't think it's Cubic's fault, at least not for that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 logo checking disk live ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244562/ubuntu-20-04-logo-checking-disk-live-iso)

Answer (score 0):

I am still positive about "update-initramfs -u"  try again after you have edited everything.
In your chroot:

```
apt update && apt upgrade
```

```
gtk-update-icon-cache Yaru || your theme
```

```
update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

```
update-initramfs -u
```

Wait till its done.