# Ubuntu 20.04 logo checking disk live ISO

Tags: boot, 20.04, customization, ubiquity

I would like to change this default ubuntu logo. The logo of the checking disk.

[image]

But I can't find it. I tried to change:

```
/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png
/usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/watermark.png
```

The first is the login screen logo while the second is the "normal" boot logo.

Do you know if this is a different image or do you know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108602/discussion-on-question-by-tarrant-ubuntu-20-04-logo-checking-disk-live-iso).

Answer (score 1):

**UBUNTU 20.04**

the live iso uses the file `initrd` which is inside `casper` directory.

[image]

this `initrd` file has the plymouth theme inside it, this is used for booting live iso. you can extract the contents and see what is being used for plymouth or any other config.

copy the `initrd` file to new directory.. and run

```
unmkinitramfs initrd .
```

[image]

[image]

So Editing the Plymouth contents as you wish and then recompile the new `initrd` file say `myinitrd` and use it to boot live iso instead of standard `initrd` file.

how to recompile the `initrd` to say `myinitrd` is a big task for me, I have offered two bounties in **stackoverflow** and **unix & linux**

Finally I got the answer from a smart person.. https://superuser.com/q/1556241/976939

the script is something like this..

```
#!/bin/bash

#mkdir 18
#unmkinitramfs initrd $HOME/18

# start with an empty file
touch $HOME/myinitrd

# Add the first microcode firmware
cd $HOME/18/early
find . -print0 | cpio --null --create --format=newc > $HOME/myinitrd

# Add the second microcode firmware
cd $HOME/18/early2
find kernel -print0 | cpio --null --create --format=newc >> $HOME/myinitrd

# Add the actual ram fs file system
cd $HOME/18/main
find . | cpio --create --format=newc | xz --format=lzma >> $HOME/myinitrd

# verify both initrds are the same
# binwalk $HOME/myinitrd
# binwalk $HOME/initrd
```

I confirm that using this method I have successfully customized the live iso Plymouth theme for the Ubuntu 20.04 ISO.