# Ubuntu 20.04 long unpacking rootfs

Tags: kernel, 20.04, initrd

i changed plymouth in Ubuntu 20.04 as here: [Ubuntu 20.04 logo checking disk live ISO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244562/ubuntu-20-04-logo-checking-disk-live-iso?newreg=c4573d27768648cca43981efd2c84112)

After recompile initrd by this code my initrd has 48MB (oryginal has 82MB).
New, recompiled initrd is smaller but is loading slower.
In my case is 10s booting diferences between default and recompiled initrd (Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs.)
When im not making any changes just recompile - it is not fast as oryginal, bigger file.
Is any way to speedup unpacking rootfs?

Comment: Are you using gzip or lz4 to compress the file?